# White line across my blender sample render?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

A nasty white line runs horizontal across my sample render and I can't seem to find what's causing it! I'm using blender internal render.

[image]

Blend File: http://www.filedropper.com/grass

Thank you! :)

Comment: Maybe it's my eyes, but I don't see any nasty white line. I downloaded the blend, and rendered it on my own machine, (screenshot: <https://www.dropbox.com/s/459vdej26h0ucot/grass.jpg?dl=0>) and I'm not sure I see it there either.

Comment: On this page, All I see is the top 40% of the image.  Everything below that is white.

Comment: This is even weirder! The image is supposed to look like @brasshat 's screenshot. But when I render it on my pc and save the image, the picture is cut off exactly where the white line appears in the preview. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like when i preview render in blender. http://i.imgur.com/YIRENa9.png

Comment: What happens if you render without the layer with the elk? That is the biggest difference I see between my screenshot and yours. And what layer are the elk in? I don't see them in the blend file I downloaded

Comment: @brasshat elk were added after the submission. The line appears with or without them. Does it seem like the line is in the same area as the bottom of my backdrop?

Comment: No. No hint of a line at all on my render.

Comment: So any suggestions? I understand that there's no line on your machine but that doesn't help me at all.

Comment: @SaraTine  I do see the line on my machine. It seems to me that the issue is on the compositor's nodes and how the edges for the background (bg) layer are interacting with other alpha channels. Other option I found was to make the mesh that has the sky texture much larger on the bottom row of vertices, so that the edge falls beyond the bottom of the camera view. The line is for sure gone that way. If any of this works for you feel free to write an answer for others to learn in the future.

Comment: @cegaton Thank you! Making the background large enough so that the edges were not in camera view worked! Not sure why the edges would make a visible line, I will post if I figure it out!

Comment: @SaraTine That's happended to me before, I'm not sure why this happens (or I would have posted a detalied answer). I don't know if it has to do with the particles or something else. I'm glad it worked though. If you figure it out please do write an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Cegaton, the line is now gone! He suggested I resize my background image, as the line coincided with the bottom of the image. Now that I resized the image so that there are no edges within the camera view, the line is gone! Thank you Cegaton!!